# OOP inheritance issue

Tags: oop

I have two classes, and the methods in them are shown below;

```
|----AVL----|     |-----RB------|
|           |     |             |
|           |     |             |
| - insert  |     | -balance    |
|           |     |             |
| - balance |     |             |
|           |     |             |
|-----------|     |-------------|
```

inside "insert" method of AVL, it calls "balance".
RB inherits AVL, so I can use insert method of AVL. Now when I call RB::insert(), it calls  AVL::insert() & then AVL::balance(), but I want it to call RB::balance() from AVL::insert(), when a RB object calls "insert".

Comment: I get the expected results on this code: https://gist.github.com/3784863. Please place a reproducible piece of code to work with. Also, what language are you using?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: In PHP all methods are virtual without exception, which is why it works for you.

Comment: @Jon: Could you elaborate on that? What are virtual methods? and what are "real" methods (or whatever)?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic case for virtual methods: make `AVL.balance` `virtual` and override it in `RB`. The correct implementation will then be called depending on what type of object calls `balance` -- it doesn't matter that the code that calls `balance` will be written as part of `AVL`.